# ListView combobox control at the end of line

Tags: vb.net

Wondering how to place combobox control as last sub item for each row with some data coming from datasource. Have this code below:

```
LvSelMat.BeginUpdate()
Dim rodzajID as String = TreeMaterials.SelectedValue
Dim rodzajName as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Text
Dim parent as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Parent.Text

 Dim li as ListViewItem
li = LvSelMat.Items.Add(parent)
li.SubItems.Add(rodzajName)
li.SubItems.Add(rodzajID)
```

'Here want to add combobox...

so far i tried like this but its only showing up combobox without any other items in row...

```
  Dim combo as new combobox
    combo.DataSource = New Variation().GetAll
    combo.DisplayMember = "Name"
    combo.ValueMember = "Id"
    combo.dropdownstyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    ' combo.height = item.bounds.height
    ' combo.location = new point(item.bounds.right, item.bounds.y)
    LvSelMat.controls.add(combo)
```

Comment: The ListView is not a DataGridView, so you will either end up floating the CBO over the active row or creating one cbo per row.  If you want/need that kind of display, why not just use a DataGridVIew - there is much less code involved populating them (as little as one line).

Comment: what i tried so far was this: dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID, new Variation().GetAll())   //get all is retreiving datatable but i get an error, also i dont know where to set display and value member for it. can you help?

Comment: @Plutonix : Ok. Lets say i will use datagridview. User will be adding data using some button. I will prepare those 4 column form datagridview creator - all 3 first columns as normal textboxcolumn and the data will be provided  from some variables and last 4th column should be filled out when user add this row clicking on some button. I dont know how to fill out this combobox and also set display and value member. I tried like this:  dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID, new Variation().GetAll())   (Get all retrun datatble)

Comment: It sounds like this cbo's contents changes for each row depending on something (keep in mind we have no idea what `Variation().GetAll` does`.  It also looks like the data is already in a TV except this cbo.  Perhaps a better way to edit them would be in a PropertyGrid: create a class to store the `rodzaj` properties, populate it and feed it to the PG.  The property which is the CBO would need a TypeConverter but would allow a dynamic list for each item (if that is what you are after)

Comment: @Plutonix combox data is the same - datasource of it is from GetAll - this method retreives datatable with Id and name - id should be trade as value member and Name as Display member, so when user add row to datagridview his first tree cells are filled up from some textboxes, and 4rd one should be filled up from this GetAll so user can select specific item out of it.

Comment: `Variation().GetAll()` would be the datasource for that cbo column.  if the user has not selected something yet the data for the row would be that value.  If there is nothing bound to the DGV you dont need the set the datasource, just feed the names to the column's `Items` collection.  This is now pretty far adrift of the actual posted Q.

Comment: i will create new post then